# Twig and relative templates

Tags: php, twig

My templates separated by modules.
And named as `moduleName:templateName`.
This template will be searched in file `<moduleNameDirectory>/templateName.twig`.

For example:

```
{% extends "firstModule:layout" %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "secondModule:inc" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Template names in `extends` and `include` processed via my loader (implements `Twig_LoaderInterface`).
And it works.

But I don't want to specify a module key inside module itself.

```
{% extends ":layout" %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "secondModule:inc" %}
{% endblock %}
```

`:layout` is within the same module as the above template.

How do I find out inside the loader methods the parent template name.
Or other way to solve this problem (without global states).

Comment: Unfortunately, loader is called totally outside the scope of the current template, I'm afraid you won't be able to know in which template you required a resource.

Comment: Thank you, Alain. But maybe there are other ways? Extend template class, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Perhaps it is hack.

Base class of templates is `Twig_Template` and it has method `loadTemplate($template, $templateName, $line, $index)`.

- `$template` that we include
- `$templateName` the current template

And base class may be extended: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options

Normalize the relative template name on the basis of parent name:

```
abstract class MyBaseTemplate extends \Twig_Template
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function loadTemplate($template, $templateName = null, $line = null, $index = null)
    {
        if (substr($template, 0, 1) === ':') {
            $parent = explode(':', $templateName, 2);
            if (count($parent) === 1) {
                throw new \MyTwigException('It is global template');
            }
            $template = $parent[0].$template;
        }        
        return parent::loadTemplate($template, $templateName, $line, $index);
    }
}

$loader = new Loader();
$options = [
    'base_template_class' => 'MyBaseTemplate',
];

$env = new \Twig_Environment($loader, $options);
$template = $env->loadTemplate('mo:page');
$content = $template->render($vars);
```